# Need a working example on Cometd 2 + Dojo 1.8 + Chat

Tags: javascript, dojo, chat, cometd

I'm looking for an example on Cometd 2 with Dojo 1.8 on Chat,

Can anybody help me out in this??

I have referred cometd.org site, and I understood the concept of cometd. But, I'm unable apply it in practically.

I just confused when to create a channel, how to publish a message from javascript to java?

I am using Eclipse Indigo IDE, Jboss 7.x server

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend you to start with reading the [CometD concepts](http://docs.cometd.org/reference/#concepts), then reading and studying the [CometD tutorials](http://docs.cometd.org/tutorials/).

Once you're done with these two, you can read and study the chat application written with Dojo that is shipped in the CometD distribution, and whose code is [here](https://github.com/cometd/cometd/tree/2.5.x/cometd-javascript/examples-dojo).

Comment: Thanks for giving answer. I tried the Cometd Tutorial's example. When I click on the "Send Hello to Server" button, it is giving the error **TypeError: _transport is null
[Break On This Error]  

_transport.send(envelope, longpoll)** what does it mean? I have followed each and every step of that given project in tutorial.